# NuSpec-generated NuGet file is resolving the wrong version of a dependency - how can I force it to do otherwise?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I have created a NuSpec file for my .NET Project as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>Author</authors>
    <description>My Project</description>
    <owners>Me</owners>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

My project also has two NuGet provided dependencies, these being:

```
<package id="Autofac" version="3.5.2" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Autofac.Extras.NLog" version="1.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
```

When I create the NuGet package for my project using this NuSpec, NuGet is smart enough to pull these addtional dependencies in. When I install my NuGet package in a new Project, I also get the `Autofac` and `Autofac.Extras.NLog` dependencies too, referenced and automatically inserted into the packages.config for my new Project.

However... the version of Autofac I get is wrong. Rather than version `3.5.2` I get version `2.6.1.841`:

```
<package id="Autofac" version="2.6.1.841" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Autofac.Extras.NLog" version="1.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
```

Now, `Autofac.Extras.NLog` has a dependency of `≥ 2.2.4.900` (at time of writing). I have two questions:

- It looks as though NuGet is first fulfilling the `Autofac.Extras.NLog` Autofac dependency by installing `Autofac 2.6.1.841`. When it then comes to fulflling my project's Autofac depdency, it is seeing that Autofac is already installed and therefore does nothing. **How can I make NuGet resolve the Autofac dependency to version `3.5.2`?**
- Even though NuGet is resolving the 'wrong' NuGet depdendency (at least for my purposes), why is it resolving to `2.6.1.841` rather than `2.2.4.900`, which is the minimum version specified in the `Autofac.Extras.NLog` dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to add these dependencies to the NuSpec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>Author</authors>
    <description>My Project</description>
    <owners>Me</owners>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="net451">
        <dependency id="Autofac" version="3.5.2"/> <!-- EXTRA DEPENDENCY -->
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

It would still be good to know if there's a solution where you don't have to maintain the NuSpec file every time there are dependency version changes in the project you're packaging.

Answer (score 0):

you can restrict artifact version to be referenced by specifying version number in a pair of square brackets. please find sample below

```
<package id="Autofac" version="[3.5.2]" targetFramework="lib/net45" />
```

edit your packages.config file with the above line , and see if that works ..!!

Comment: This works fine if you do it in the consuming project. However, I don't think it works if you put it in the project which is packaged by NuGet. I don't want the consumers of my project to have to add this NuGet Reference themselves, or thereafter doctor it to be at Version 3.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Nuget 3.5 (now in Beta) finally solved this issue. I tested on my project and the dependencies were calculated correctly (Nuget 3.4 didn't calculate them correctly).

[Nuget download page](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html)

This is the pull request:
https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/pull/632/files